# Computing with ideals:  over $K$ or over $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K$? does it matter?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

I'm beginning to learn to use [SINGULAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SINGULAR), the [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) (CAS) for commutative algebra.

**NOTATION:** If $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq K$; otherwise $\mathbb{Z}_p\!\subseteq\!K$ for some prime $p\!=\!\mathrm{char}\,K$. 
If $S\subseteq\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\!=\!\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]\subseteq K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\!=\!K[\mathbf{x}]$, let $\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$ denote the ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]$ generated by polinomials from $S$; and let $\langle S\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$ denote the ideal in $K[\mathbf{x}]$ generated by polinomials from $S$.

From what I understand, CASs are able to carry out computations in $K[\mathbf{x}]$ only when $K$ is either $\mathbb{Q}$ or finite (and some other special cases).

**QUESTION:** when doing the standard operations with a CAS on ideals, such as intersection, multiplication, addition, intersection with subrings (elimination of variables), etc. within $\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]$, **how much can we deduce about the corresponding ideals in $K[\mathbf{x}]$**?

More concretely:

1. does $\langle S_1\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S_2\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$ imply $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$?
2. does $\langle S_1\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}\cap\langle S_2\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$ imply $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}\cap\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$?
3. does $\langle S_1\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}\;\cdot\;\langle S_2\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$ imply $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}\;\cdot\;\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$?
4. does $\langle S_1\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}+\langle S_2\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$ imply $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}+\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$?
5. for $f\!\in\!\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]$, does $f\!\in\!\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}\Leftrightarrow f\!\in\!\langle  S\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$ hold?
6. etc. (Elimination of variables, Zariski Closure of the Image, Solving Polynomial Equations, Radical Membership, Quotient of Ideals, ...)

Basically what I'm asking is **how can we use Singular (and other CASs) for computation in  polynomial rings over an arbitrary field** (but all polynomials have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$).

My main literature is *[A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540735410)* (the authors of the book are the developers of Singular). I would think these questions would be adressed somewhere in that book, but I was not able to find such propositions (I just began reading it). Anyone know where to look?

P.S. if $S\!\subseteq\!R'\!\leq\!R$, where $R',R$ are commutative rings with 1, does $\langle S\rangle_{R'}=\langle S\rangle_R\cap R'$ hold?

Comment: Regarding your PS: I supose you are talking about ideals... It may well be the case that $S$ has exactly one element, which is moreover invertible in $R$ but not in $R'$. Then $1$ is in the ideal generated by $S$ in $R$, so $1$ is in $(S)\cap R'$, yet $1$ is not in $(S)_{R'}$.

Comment: Aha, so $\langle S\rangle_{R'}\neq\langle S\rangle_R\cap R'$ in general; thanks. And yes, I'm talking about ideals: if $R$ is a any ring and $S\!\subseteq\!R$, then the ideal generated by $S$ is $\langle S\rangle:=\bigcap\{I; S\!\subseteq\!I\!\unlhd\!R\}$. And when $R$ is commutative unital, we have $\langle S\rangle=\sum RS$, i.e. the set of all finite $R$-linear combinations of elements of $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Proof of the implications in the original question.

(1), (3) and (4) come from definitions. Namely, let $I=\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb Q|x}$.

- $\langle S\rangle_{K|x}=I K[\bf{x}]$ is the ideal of $K[{\bf x}]$ generated by $I\subset K[{\bf x}]$. So $I_1=I_2$ implies that $I_1 K[{\bf{x}}]=I_2 K[\bf{x}]$. This is (1).
- $I_1\cdot I_2$ is the ideal generated by the elements of the form $s_1.s_2$ with $s_i\in S_i$. Similarly, $I_1K[{\bf{x}}]\cdot I_1K[{\bf{x}}]$ is the ideal of $K[{\bf{x}}]$ generated by the same elements, but in $K[{\bf{x}}]$. 
  The ideal $(I_1\cdot I_2)K[{\bf{x}}]$ is generated by as well by the same elements. This implies that $I_1K[{\bf{x}}]\cdot I_1K[{\bf{x}}]=(I_1\cdot I_2)K[{\bf{x}}]$.
- Similarly, $I_1+I_2$ is generated by $S_1\cup S_2$ and one can follow the same reasonning as above.

For (2), we have the exact sequence 
$$ 0 \to I_1\cap I_2 \to I_1\times I_2 \to I_1+I_2 \to 0$$ 
of $\mathbb Q[{\bf x}]$-modules. It remains exact when tensored with $K[{\bf x]}$ because the latter is free over $\mathbb Q[{\bf x}]$. Now the new exact sequence is 
$$ 0\to (I_1\cap I_2)K[{\bf x}]\to I_1 K[{\bf x}]\times I_2 K[{\bf x}] \to I_1 K[{\bf x}]+ I_2 K[{\bf x}]\to 0.$$
Compare with the canonical exact sequence
$$ 0 \to I_1K[{\bf x}]\cap I_2K[{\bf x}] \to I_1K[{\bf x}]\times I_2K[{\bf x}] \to I_1K[{\bf x}]+I_2K[{\bf x}] \to 0$$ 
then you get $(I_1\cap I_2)K[{\bf x}]=I_1K[{\bf x}]\cap I_2K[{\bf x}]$. This is (2).

Below is the old part showing the inverse implications.

For any ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Q[{\bf x}]$ (your $\langle S\rangle_{\mathbb Q|x}$), denote by $I_K$ the ideal of $K[\bf{x}]$ generated by the elements of $I\subseteq K[\bf{x}]$. This is your $\langle S\rangle_{K|x}$.

> Claim: If $I_K=J_K$ for two ideals of $\mathbb Q[\bf{x}]$. Then $I=J$.

Proof: Let $\{ e_i \}_i$ be a basis of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ (as vector space). We can suppose that one of them, $e_{i_0}=1$. Then $K[\bf {x}]$ is the direct sum of $\mathbb Q[\bf{x}]$ and the $e_i\mathbb Q[\bf{x}]$, $i\ne i_0$. This implies that $I_K=I\oplus (\oplus_{i\ne i_0} Ie_i)$. Hence 
$$I_K\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf x}]=I.$$
In particular, $I_K=J_K$ implies $I=J$.

The claim implies (1). For (2), note that 
$$(I_K\cap J_K)\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf{x}}] = (I_K\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf{x}}]) \cap (J_K\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf{x}}])=I\cap J.$$
For (3) and (4),  note that $I_K\cdot J_K=(I\cdot J)_K$. For (5), you are looking for the equality $f\mathbb Q[{\bf{x}}]+I=I$, it is enough to apply (4).

A deep reason for all of this is $K$ is "faithfully flat" over $\mathbb Q$. For your PS, the equality holds if $R'\to R$ is faithfully flat.

<s>When you are dealing with $\mathbb F_p$ (field with $p$ elements), the result is false. For example, $I=p\mathbb Z[x]$ is equal to $0$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ but $I\ne 0$.</s>  Misreading.

The same arguments apply for any field extensions, in particular if $\mathbb Q$ is replaced by a finite field.

**More on the PS** If $R'\to R$ is **faithfully** flat, then $\langle S \rangle_R\cap R'=\langle S\rangle_{R'}$.

Proof: Let $I=\langle S\rangle_{R'}$. Then $\langle S \rangle_R$ is equal to the ideal of $R$ generated by $I$, usually denoted by $IR$. Obviously $I\subseteq IR\cap R'$. Consider the $R'$-module $(IR\cap R')/I$ and tensor it by $R$ over $R'$. Then you get $0$. By definition of faithful flatness, this implies that $(IR\cap R')/I=0$, so $IR\cap R'=I$.

Note that flatness is not enough: consider $R'=\mathbb Z$, $R=\mathbb Q$ and $I=2\mathbb Z$ (cf. Mariano's comment).

Comment: Aha, the proof of (1): If $\langle S_1\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S_2\rangle_{\mathbb{Q}[\mathbf{x}]}$, then $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf x}]=\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}\cap \mathbb Q[{\bf x}]$, hence $S_1\subseteq\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$ and $S_2\subseteq\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$, so $\langle S_1\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}=\langle S_2\rangle_{K[\mathbf{x}]}$. An excellent answer, thank you :).

Comment: Just one more question. An R-module is [flat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) when $-\otimes_RM$ is an exact functor, i.e. maps every short exact sequence of modules to an exact sequence. It is known that every projective (in particular free) module is flat, hence $_\mathbb{Q}K$ is flat. But I do not understand, what does flatness have to do with my problem? How can I show that if $R'\!\leq\!R$ are rings (commutative unital?) and $S\!\subseteq\!R'$, then flatness of the $R'$-module $R$ implies $\langle S\rangle_{R'}=\langle S\rangle_R\cap R'$?

Comment: I misread (1). (1) as well as the modified (2)-(4) essentially come from the definition of ideal generated by a subset. They hold for any ring extensions. My proof is for the inverse implications and need faithfully flat extensions.

Comment: After rereading your proof, I don't think I understand (2). Didn't you prove the converse of it? How can I prove (2)?

Comment: @LeonLampret: yes you are right I proved the other implication (as I said in a comment above). I will edit my answer.